Why is running a query with boolean 'group by' not working with gorp's SelectRow, but it's working when I run it directly in a database shell?
Here's the sql fiddle. This is just an example I made up, the real query is not about sales and products, but the structure of the query more or less is the same (but more complicated).
The query looks something like this:
select 
    count(sales.id) as total_sale_in_period,
    case 
        when product.production_date < '2024-01-01' then sum(product.price)
        else 0
    end as product_shipped_last_year_total_price,
    case 
        when product.production_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-07-01' then sum(product.price) 
        else 0
    end as product_shipped_first_semester_total_price
from product 
left join sales on sales.product_id = product.id
where product.production_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-07-01'
or product.production_date < '2024-01-01'
group by 
    product.production_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-07-01',
    product.production_date < '2024-01-01';

The result looks something like:



total_sale_in_period
product_shipped_last_year_total_price
product_shipped_first_semester_total_price




0
2000
0


2
0
3000



The problem is I can't use the query above in gorp because of the grouping, but when I run it in a database shell, it works fine.
I can't just grouped it with product.production_date because the grouping I want is between '2024-01-01' and '2024-07-01' and before '2024-01-01' just like in the query example.
With gorp, I got this error: pq: column \"product.production_date\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
I have already tried to do this, and it doesn't work:
select 
    count(sales.id) as total_sale_in_period,
        case 
        when product.production_date < '2024-01-01' then sum(product.price)
        else 0
    end as product_shipped_last_year_total_price,
    case 
        when product.production_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-07-01' then sum(product.price) 
        else 0
    end as product_shipped_first_semester_total_price,
        case 
        when product.production_date < '2024-01-01' then 'last_year'
                when product.production_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-07-01' then 'first_semester'
        else 'other'
    end as production_date_group,
from product 
left join sales on sales.product_id = product.id
where product.production_date between '2024-01-01' and '2024-07-01'
or product.production_date < '2024-01-01'
group by 
    production_date_group;

